# Transfer control from popup to content script - Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

PRINT SCREEN to understand my problem : [link](http://www.scitechexplained.com/magazine/chromeproblem.JPG)

I'm building an extension which inserts a button into a specific web page's DOM. This insertion is achieved by the **injectScript()** function from insert.js which is correctly executed and correctly entered in the **"content_scripts"**: field of the manifest file.

**injectScript()** injects (in the DOM of the currently loaded webpage, if it's, of course, the page I'm looking for) a script tag containing the same inject.js (that contains the onclick event for the button), a style tag containing the CSS for the button, and most importantly, a div that contains a text obtained from **background.html** by calling **chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "dami"}, function(response) {...});** the text inserted in this div is used to populate some other div from the webpage by clicking on the button which I inserted.

This works perfectly but I also need to solve another issue:

The specific text which I inject into the webpage's DOM **is injected only** when **chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged** , **chrome.tabs.onUpdated**, and **chrome.history.onVisited** events happen. I also want to **re-inject** this text whenever my **popup.html modifies it by changing localStorage["builtin"]**. So what I want is this: when I click the OK button from the popup.html page I want to use **chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "reintrodu"}, function(response) {...});** from popup.html to send a request to the same content script that managed my first text injection, but it seems it doesn't work.

Nothing happens when I click the button! the *test* alert boxes don't show anything. When I press the OK button the popup.html just closes and no exchange of data seems to happen.

This is the function that is triggered by the OK button from my popup.html :

```
function closer() 
{
    if ($('input[name=check]').is(':checked'))
    {
        localStorage["builtin"] = document.getElementById("tkey_1").value;
        localStorage["build"] = "true";
    }
    else 
    {
        localStorage["builtin"] = document.getElementById("tkey_1").value;
        localStorage["build"] = "false";            
    }

    chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "reintrodu"}, function(response)
    {
        alert(response.farewell);
    });         

    window.close();
}
```

**chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "reintrodu"}, function(response) {...})** should send the request to the content script that is **inject.js**:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
//      console.log(sender.tab ? "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url : "from the extension");
if (request.greeting === "history")
 {
    console.log("registered in history");
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye from history"});
    PageShowHandler();
 }   
else if (request.greeting === "historyrem")
 {
    console.log("registered in historyrem");
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye from historyrem"});
    PageShowHandler();
 }       
else if (request.greeting === "exploit")
 { 
    console.log("registered in exploit");
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye from exploit"});
    PageShowHandler();
 }
else if (request.greeting === "reintrodu") 
 { 
    console.log("registered in reintrodu");
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye from reintrodu"});
    //PageShowHandler();
    alert('prins reintrodu');
 }   
else if (request.greeting === "selected")
 {
    console.log("registered in selected");
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye from selected"});
    PageShowHandler();
 }

else
    sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

And this is **background.html** which seems do to the job for the initial injection, unlike popup.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Fired when a URL is visited, providing the HistoryItem data for that URL.
chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tabId, selectInfo)
{
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabId, {greeting: "selected"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) 
{
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {greeting: "exploit"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
    });
});

chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function(result)
{
    //alert(result.url);
    //chrome.tabs.sendRequest(null, {greeting: "history"}, function(response) {
    //      console.log(response.farewell);
    //});
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w) 
    {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(w.id, function (tabul)
        {
            //alert(tabul.id);
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabul.id, {greeting: "history"}, function(response) {
                    console.log(response.farewell);
            });
        });
    });     
});


chrome.history.onVisitRemoved.addListener(function(removed)
{
    //alert(result.url);
    //chrome.tabs.sendRequest(null, {greeting: "historyrem function(response) {
    //      console.log(response.farewell);
    //});
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w) 
    {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(w.id, function (tabul)
        {
            //alert(tabul.id);
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabul.id, {greeting: "historyrem"}, function(response) {
                    console.log(response.farewell);
            });
        });
    });     
});

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
{
    if(request.greeting == "dami")
    {
        if(localStorage["build"] == "true")
        {   
            sendResponse({farewell: localStorage["builtin"]});
        }
        else
        {
            sendResponse({farewell: "textul default"});
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        sendResponse({farewell: "n-am ba; du-te dracu!"});
    }
});


</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

This is the manifest:

```
{
"name" : "gMail Adder ",
"version" : "1.0",
"description" : "Google Chrome Gmail Adder",
"options_page": "options.html",
"background_page": "background.html",
"run_at": "document_start",
"permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "history",
   "http://*/*",
   "https://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["*://*.google.mail.com/*", "https://*.google.mail.com/*"     ,"http://mail.google.com/*" ,"https://mail.google.com/*", "https://www.google.com/*", "http://www.google.com/*", "file:///*"],
   "css": ["toggle.css"],
   "js": ["jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "inject.js"]
  }
],
"browser_action" : {
"default_icon" : "Quest Icon 11.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing a popup window before receiving a response from the request because API calls are asynchronous.

Also if you want to send a request to a content script you need to use `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` instead.

So your popup should look like this:

```
function closer() 
{
    ...

    //todo: get tabid of a tab where the content script you are interested in is

    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabId, {greeting: "reintrodu"}, function(response)
    {
        alert(response.farewell);

        //closing only after receiving response
        window.close();
    });         


}
```

Comment: how do I get `tabId`?